# How to make BufWritePre work with :wa?

Tags: vim

I have a `BufWritePre` hook, which unfortunately doesn't work with `:wa`, only with `:w` (and also with `:wq`).

How can I make it work with `:wa` as well?

This is a hook I have in my `.vimrc`: `autocmd BufWritePre *.c* :ClangFormat`

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't work with both wq? Can you post an example of your autocommand?

Comment: You're right, it looks like it works with `:wq`. I have added autocommand to my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`BufWritePre` are run only when the buffers are actually written.  `:w` forces write, while `:wall` doesn't, it only writes those buffers that are modified.  If you want to force writing all buffers (modified or not) you can do something like `:bufdo w`.  This will also run `BufWritePre` and friends.

Comment: It's strange because now when I try `:bufdo w` I get: `No write since the last change (...)` but when I type `:w` it works fine.